# Treeview menu Control by access user

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, treeview, erp

I wanna to get a specific value for sql server.
The sql table is as below now.

```
**ID  /      PW   /    Depart**  
AAA   /    1234   /  1   
BBB   /    2345   /  2   
...      
**LKL** /  8765  /  **9**
```

For example,
When LKL user access to Logon Form,
I want to get the Depart code 9.

But it working not. 
Maybe some problem. But I couldn't find that no more.

Here is my code. I will preciate any ideas.

Thanks.

```
private void MForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logon lf = new Logon();
            String tx = lf.IDTBox.Text;
            String str = "Server = 102.201.10.17; Database = Dorw; UID = sa; Password = 565p89";
            String qur = "SELECT Depart FROM dbo.PW WHERE Name = @tx";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qur, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tx", tx);
            con.Open();
            using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            switch (reader.ToString())
            {
            case "0":
                break;

            case "1":
                treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes[1].Remove();
                break;

            case "9":
                treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Remove();
                treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes[0].Remove();
                treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes[1].Remove();
                break;
            }
       con.Close();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

`SqlDataReader.ToString()` doesn't return inside data of it. This will *probably* return the name of the type.

Since your reader returns one column, you can use `(string)reader[0]` as switch expression.

But if wanna read your reader, since default position of the `SqlDataReader` is *before* the first record, you must call `Read` to begin accessing any data.

```
while(reader.Read())
{
   switch ((string)reader[0])
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

But honestly I don't understand why you keep these integer values as a character. Would be better to save them as an integer and cast them to string in your program.

As a better option, you can use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is returns first row of the first column which looks like this is exactly what you want.

```
string value = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
switch(value)
{
   ...
}
```

Also use `using` statement to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` instead of calling `.Close()` method manually. As a best practice, don't use `AddWithValue` method. It *may* generates unexpected and surprising results. Use [`.Add()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add.aspx) instead.

- [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)